# Simple filtering proxy returning HTTP 500 for images

Tags: proxy, httpserver

For quick testing, I need an HTTP server which forwards all requests(including ones to "directories") to another server and returns the response, except if the requested url ends with ".jpg".

Is there something simple in e.g. bash or python?

I want to simulate that a server runs normally, but returns HTTP 500 for all images (jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your .jpg server is connected to your second server, whenever the .jpg server receives a request, it could send a request to the second server.

In the following example, the client's request is the following.

```
GET index.html HTTP/1.1
```

In this case, you would repeat the request on the socket that connects to the second server, and then repeat the response to the client. This might be a bit slow though.

Now let's take a look at this request...

```
GET logo.jpg HTTP/1.1
```

Your server could identify the file type of the request and if it recognises ".jpg" then it could return the requested file. Or it could check if the file exists in the local file system.

Big Edit: If you want to return HTTP 500 after it's done, then instead of returning the requested file, return a HTTP status code

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Error
Server: Basic Python/Bash Server
Connection: close
```

Don't forget to add an empty line and make sure you separate each line using CR (\r) + LF (\n).
End of Big Edit.

Good luck!